# Symfony 2 twig bad credentials trans bug

Tags: symfony, twig

Good day.
I'm having 2 projects in Symfony 2. In first, i'm using {{ error.message|trans }} to translate 
"Bad credentials" authorization error message. It calls Translator class trans method from Component\Translation\Translator.php to translate this string.

```
public function trans($id, array $parameters = array(), $domain = null, $locale = null)
{
    if (null === $locale) {
        $locale = $this->getLocale();
    }

    if (null === $domain) {
        $domain = 'messages';
    }

    if (!isset($this->catalogues[$locale])) {
        $this->loadCatalogue($locale);
    }

    return strtr($this->catalogues[$locale]->get((string) $id, $domain), $parameters);
}
```

It works correctly, and returns translated string from messages.domain.yml file. In second project, i'm using same settings, and trying to translate error string in twig in the same way. But it doesn't working, and the original 'Bad credentials' string is returned. After inspection, i found, that Component\Translation\IdentityTranslator.php class is creating(instead of Translator.php), and it's method trans is being called:

```
   /**
   * IdentityTranslator does not translate anything.
   *
   * @author Fabien Potencier <fabien@symfony.com>
   *
   * @api
   */
   class IdentityTranslator implements TranslatorInterface
   {
       /// More code here
       public function trans($id, array $parameters = array(), $domain = null, $locale = null)
       {
          return strtr((string) $id, $parameters);
       } 
   }
```

So, it just returns the original message. What could be potential source of such problem? Is it Symfony bug? (Both projects uses Symfony 2.4.4)